# Mudar a fonte do console

Tags: c#, console

Na foto abaixo, eu posso mudar a fonte do console clicando no topo da janela e clicando em propriedades:
[image]
Mas como eu posso mudar a fonte e o tamanho da fonte do console através de programação?

Comment: Da uma lida aqui, talvez ajude:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631634/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-c-sharp

Comment: Ajudou bastante (-: obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Boa sorte!